# Angular: Print Null from an asynchronous data that contains null

Tags: angular, angular-fullstack

I am fetching the data from backend (Node.js/Express.js + Oracledb) which contains some null values. I want to print Null in the table in HTML where the data contains null. Is there a way that I can do that?

My code:

.component.html

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table style = "text-align: center; margin: auto;">
    <thead>
      <th>
        Company Code
      </th>
      <th>
        Company Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Company Sub Mode
      </th>
      <th>
        Short Details
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor = "let compData of companyData">
      <tr>
        <td>{{compData[0][0]}}</td>
        <td>{{compData[0][1]}}</td> //here I want to print Null if the value from the backend contains null
        <td>{{compData[0][2]}}</td>
        <td>{{compData[0][3]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

.component.ts

```
processListByNum()
{
  
  const params = new HttpParams().set('id', test)

  this.http.get<{[key: string] : Corporate}> 
  ('http://localhost:3000/api/searchCompany', {params})
  .pipe(map(responseData => {
      const postsArray : Corporate [] = [];

      for(const key in responseData)
      {
        if(responseData.hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
          postsArray.push({...responseData[key], idkey: key});
        }
      }
      return postsArray;
  }))
  .subscribe(posts => {

    this.companyData = posts;
    console.log(this.companyData);
  }
,error => {
  console.log("Error occurred while searching the company " + error.message);

})
}

}
```

Comment: Can you share the .ts file ?

Comment: @RamiLoiferman, I edited the question

Comment: It also fails before the response from server ?

Comment: Can you try set initial value of this.companyData to [[]]? 
And also do the same in case empty response from server ?

Comment: No, its working fine. The database contains some data with null values. I want to print those null values using Angular.

Comment: Ok maybe try inside the .map to map null to Null string ?

Comment: Did this worked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you get null from `compData[0][1]`

then you can try

```
{{compData && compData[0] && compData[0][1] ? compData[0][1] : 'Null'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `compData` is also am array, you can use something like this

```
<tbody>
      <tr>
              // Since you are already running in a loop, one td element is enough.
              <td  *ngFor = "let compData of companyData[0]">
                       {{ compData ? compData : 'Null' }}
              </td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```